# Text transform when displaying user generated content

Tags: website-design, letter-case

Given something like the below, which lists user input content:

```
First Name | Last Name
-----------+-----------
John       | Doe
john       | doe
JOHN       | DOE
johN       | doE
```

Is it good practice to transform the case upon displaying the data? For example `uppercase`:

```
First Name | Last Name
-----------+-----------
JOHN       | DOE
JOHN       | DOE
JOHN       | DOE
JOHN       | DOE
```

Or `capitalize`:

```
First Name | Last Name
-----------+-----------
John       | Doe
John       | Doe
John       | Doe
John       | Doe
```

Keep in mind that I'm not asking about transformation upon *input*, I'm asking about transformation upon *output* of the data.

### Edit: Let's add some context.

So this is actually an address book feature of a webshop. The user can see a list of the different addresses that they shipped/billed to. So this list shows content generated by the user *himself* exclusively.

The data will obviously be displayed elsewhere (and I realize it *might* make sense to capitalize the entire address when printing shipping labels), but the question is specifically about the addressbook feature.

Comment: Who is consuming this data? Do you perceive a benefit to those users in changing the case? I can imagine a slight readability benefit in some situations, perhaps.

Comment: Beware that if you choose to capitalize the first letter **only**, a name like <i>McDonalds</i> will not be quite the same as <i>Mcdonalds</i>

Comment: Primarily the user who input the data himself. Personally, I do not perceive a benefit. It was a request I got that I find dubious.

Comment: I think it’s better to give the user the opportunity to sanitize stored data. There’re so many reasons for caps not being where a simple algorithm might expect them. It would be worse, of course, to apply the transformation to the stored data, especially when done without user confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Keep it as it is.

This is because the data entered by the user is as per how he wants to spell his name and capitalizing the first letters might against how he wants his name to be spelt (If you think that is weird, here is [an interesting article](http://www.danah.org/name.html) from a person who dislikes capitalizing his name ). To quote the article

> **danah michele boyd**
>
> No, i did not forget to capitalize that, but i've quickly learned that
>   most people don't appreciate my decision to leave the capitalization
>   out of my name. There are a lot of reasons that i got rid of the
>   capital letters in the final name change, some personal and some
>   political.
>
> First, there's my mother's original desire to have balance and my
>   adult appreciation of that (as a child, i was just cranky that i could
>   never find anything with my name on it). danah balances; Danah does
>   not. In fact, my entire name balances quite conveniently, in all of
>   its forms: danah michele mattas beard boyd. There's something elegant
>   about that.
>
> There's also the political. I was always bothered by the fact that the
>   first person singular pronoun is capitalized in english - i always
>   thought it was quite self-righteous. Or, as Douglas Adams noted,
>   "Capital letters were always the best way of dealing with things you
>   didn't have a good answer to." Ever since i was a kid, i was told that
>   the world does not revolve around me, yet our written culture is
>   telling me something entirely different. Why not capitalize 'we' or
>   'they'? (Yes, i love the work of bell hooks.)
>
> So, i started researching where the capitalization of said pronoun
>   came from and was quite stunned to find that it was always capitalized
>   because it always appeared as the first word in a sentence, never
>   stuck in the middle. And then, when it started appearing in the
>   middle, it started getting capitalized out of convention and because
>   people worried that it would get lost in script. Of course, "It's odd,
>   and a little unsettling, to reflect upon the fact that English is the
>   only major language in which "I" is capitalized; in many other
>   languages "You" is capitalized and the "i" is lower case" (journalist
>   Sydney J. Harris).

Here is what amazon does (I hid the addresses for privacy sake :) )

[image]

If you see the example above, though I have used multiple variations of how my name had been entered, Amazon took it as it is and used it since users might have different expectations on how the name should be customized